# Can I trigger a play for hosts not in a specific group?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like take two different provisioning actions for hosts in and not in a specific group.  For example:

```
- hosts: nis_server
  tasks:
  - name: Set up NIS server

- hosts: ~nis_server
  tasks:
  - name: Use NIS server for authentication & login
```

Is there a syntax/operator to invert a group without having to manually/scriptually create a complement group?

Note: I tried using the ~ syntax above, surprisingly ansible actually accepts this, but simply ignores the tilde, so ~nis_server is the same as nis_server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [patterns](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_patterns.html) documentation: `all:!nis_server`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run playbook against one single server/node though you have mentioned about host or group in playbook.

## ansible-playbook -l rhel7c1 remove_httpd.yml